# How to *correctly* round to the nearest multiple

Tags: rounding-error

I am struggling to find the correct implementation for rounding to the nearest multiple. I thought the simple arithmetic of `[number/multiple]*multiple` would give me my solution but I am running into instances where this is false. I am trying to mimic Excel's `MROUND` function.

Given the number `422.3710249` and the multiple `.00125`, I receive a number that is off by a certain level of precision... see javascript example to get the number.

```
console.log(Math.round(422.3710249/.00125)*.00125) = 422.37125000000003
```

Where my solution faulty? I expect this: `422.37125`

---

- `<0` and `0` do not concern me
- [Math.round documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Comment: See [this question and answers (57 of them!)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1458633/428857) for more than you wanted to know on this topic.

Comment: And for anyone else who should have known: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-3693/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that floating point numbers are not able to represent any real number. You are getting the right result **using floating point arithmetic**. The closest number to $422.37125$ the computer can represent using floats is $422.37125000000003$.

Comment: It's more complicated than that. JavaScript uses IEEE 754 64-bit double precision throughout, and the two such numbers closest to $422.37125$ are $422.3712500000000318323\ldots$ and $422.3712499999999749888\ldots$ So you can see that the closest number to $422.37125$ should actually be displayed as $422.37124999999997$, not $422.37125000000003$. So I'm a bit puzzled by that, especially as the closest 64-bit representation of $0.00125$ is _less_ than $0.00125$, so I would expect the result of the multiplication to be too small if anything.